# A confusion with solenoidal windings

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

I have seen in solenoids, toroids, transformers, electromagnets and machines that the core is pretty insulated. Over this the winding coil is wrapped but it is a bare coil (turns are not insulated to each other). So, how does it work? Won`t there be a short circuited path (current will find a shorter path and flow through it and will not flow through the whole winding)? I have more precisely and vividly stated it in the picture([image])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most wires like this are, in fact, insulated; a very thin layer of enamel coats the wires. You can gently scrape away this layer with a key or some sandpaper; the copper beneath will be a slightly different colour.

Comment: But will be the skinny enamel coating insulation sufficiently strong to prevent the electrical breakdown?

Comment: Dielectric breakdown strengths are usually measured in kilovolts per millimeter; the electric field between the coils is orders of magnitude weaker than this.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy...may be that is the reason behind this...nevertheless, in transformers you can find how drastically the primary and secondary winding are insulated by piece board and tapes, even if the winding has enamel coating over it. I am sharing a video link which will make me clearer.:-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6NyTprQCBI